# C#. Dependency Injection. Помогите с вопросом на собеседовании

Tags: c#, задание-на-собеседовании

На техническом собеседоании мне задали вопрос:

> Сколько живет объект, после его регистрации в DI ?

Вопрос меня обескуражил, я сначала подумал что речь о Singleton,  Scope и Transient. Правильного ответа не знаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я должен был ответить?

Comment: Если вы объект регистрируете, то наверное он живет столько же, сколько контейнер. Для scope и transient обычно регистрируют не объект, а его тип или фабрику для его создания.

Comment: Может стоит переименовать вопрос на "Сколько живет объект, после его регистрации в DI контейнере?"